# how to focus or selection 'Global Attribute' hidden in css

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="form-container" id="form-container" hidden>
    <div class="form-title" style="display: flex;">
        <span>Add bookmark</span>
        <span>x</span>
    </div>
```

is it some kind of type-alias, visibility or display:none or some other type of shortcut?

which other global attribute in css can replace to select or class="hidden " ?

Thanks

Comment: hidden === 'display:none' nothing else can replace this property

Comment: user agent stylesheet will be modified `div[Attributes Style] { display: none; }`